# Change time format using pandas

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a column with time format as ie 1200, how could I change in that format 12:00:00 ?

```
df['start_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df.start_time, format='%H:%M:%S')
```

Using the above I took the following error
ValueError: time data u'1200' does not match format '%H:%M' (match)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
df['start_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df.start_time, format='%H%M').dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```